# Display only one category with mutliple files in treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, treeview

I have a treeview that is showing categories and the files that go with them.  What I am running in to is that each category is showing multiple times and displaying the new file added on each upload.  What I want to do is display the category once, then each item that goes underneath it.

I tried moving the foreach to just above the link to the file, but then i couldn't figure out how to display the category names.

This is my current markup

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tree">
    @if (Model.Collaboration.Files.Any())
    {
        foreach (var file in Model.Collaboration.Files)
        {
            <div class="treeview">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <label>
                            @if (file.Category != null)
                            {
                                <span>@file.Category.Name</span>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <span>Uncategorized</span>
                            }                                         
                        </label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                @Html.ActionLink(file.Filename, "ShowFile", "Attachments", new { @id = file.Id, collaborationId = Model.Collaboration.Id }, new { target = "_blank" })
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

My Model

```
public class AttachmentCategory
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your will nested loops (outer loop for `Category` and inner loop for the categories collection of files).. You need to post your models (typeof `Category` should have `IEnumerable<File> Files` or similar

Comment: Please explain more. I don't understand

Comment: OK, I assume you don't have a model that represents what you want to display, in which case you need to create one. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: I added a model. I need to just display the name then all the items that come from a sepearate model under them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could possibly include conditional statements in you view to store the `category.Name` property in a variable, and test in each iteration if the `category.Name` matches the stored value (and omit the `<label>` tag if it does) this would be rather messy and also require your files to be sorted by `category.Name`. The easiest way to solve this is with a view model that represents what you want to display. You have not shown the full details of all your models so this is a simplified example

```
public class FileVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryVM
{
  public string ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<FileVM> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
  List<CategoryVM> model = new List<CategoryVM>();
  // populate your collection of categories, and for each category, populate its collection of files
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<CategoryVM>
<ul>
  @foreach(CategoryVM category in Model)
  {
    <li>
      <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => category.Name)</span>
      <ul>
        @foreach(FileVM file in category.Files)
        {
          <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(file.Filename, "ShowFile", "Attachments", new { id = file.ID, collaborationId = category.ID }, new { target = "_blank" })
          </li>
        }
      </ul>
    <li>
  }
<ul>
```

Side note:

1. Not sure what the checkbox is for (it has no `name` attribute so
   wont post back anything)
2. There is no point using a `<label>` tag - its not associated with
   any control so its not really a label.
3. It would be better to assign "Uncategorized" to the
   `CategoryVM.Name` property where apropriate rather than using
   unnecessary `if` statements in the view.